# The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID named 'SharePoint Online Client Extensibility Web Application Principal'

Tags: spfx, aadhttpclient

**I am trying to connect my spfx webpart to aad secured web api through adhttpclient. i get the below error.**

> InteractionRequiredAuthError: AADSTS65001: The user or administrator
> has not consented to use the application with ID
> '1c59b498-2b59-4ef1-9523-eb06f33c8b97' named 'SharePoint Online Client
> Extensibility Web Application Principal'. Send an interactive
> authorization request for this user and resource. Trace ID:
> e3715c28-c147-483c-862c-87d08ad34b02 Correlation ID:
> bf9431dc-cfca-43bc-961e-4357b75dfc5c Timestamp: 2023-11-29 11:22:13Z

**None of the permissions given below are working.**

[image]